# Performance difference between def and val

Tags: scala, callbyname

Consider the below code where I am passing a method and a function as a parameter to map()

```
  val list1:List[Int]=List(10,20,30)

  def func1(x:Int):Int={
      x+10
  }

  list1.map(func1)
  list1.map(_+10)
```

I have few questions about ETA expansion:

- Is there a performance difference in using a method in place of a function, especially since the method is internally getting converted into a function?
- Is there a performance difference between `def x:Int=10` and `val x:Int=10`?
- I have read that the call-by-name parameter is actually a method which does not accept any parameter. Now, if methods are not objects, how are we using a method as a parameter value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no significant difference between the expressions you're asking about.

`val x` incurs a private field.

Note that `vs.map(_+10)` inlines the function, as compared to `vs.map(x => f(x))`. But you have to create a function object in any case.

A call-by-name argument `=> X` is a `() => X` under the hood.

From the REPL, use `javap` to show code. `-c` for code, `-v` for verbose.

```
scala> vs.map(f)
res0: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)

scala> :javap -pv -
[snip]
```

Comment: =>X is actually () =>X then how are we invoking the function without ()

Comment: The definition of call-by-name is just that a reference evaluates the expression; it does that by invoking the function.

Answer (score 0):

One of the differences is, `val` values are measured when class is loaded whilst `def` are measured when called.

A simple example is, say you have 100K `val` variables in the class (for argument's sake), the system might take long time to start. But if you have a `def A` in which declares 100K `val`. The performance will be hit only when the `A` is called.